# Why is as.POSIXct outputting BST instead of UTC?

Tags: r, posixct

```
as.POSIXct("Tue Aug 18 2020 08:45:02 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)", tx="UTC", format = "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2020-07-13 08:24:03 BST"
```

same output with GMT instead of UTC set as the timezone

```
as.POSIXct("Tue Aug 18 2020 08:45:02 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)", tx="GMT", format = "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2020-07-13 08:24:03 BST"
```

for reference I'm doing this in Rstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for timezone is "tz" not "tx". This works as expected:

```
> as.POSIXct("Tue Aug 18 2020 08:45:02 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)", tz="UTC", format = "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2020-08-18 08:45:02 UTC"
```